# Is there a way to watch content of a q-select with use-input property?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

Is there a way to watch the text content of a q-input with use-input attribute, please ?

I want to create an autocomplete bar for addresses. First I tried with a separated q-input and q-select and it worked : I watch the v-model of my q-input and I use it to fetch addresses suggestions with my autocomplete API, then I display them on the q-select.

But I want to merge the q-input and q-select, so I added `use-input` to my q-select, but now the watcher on its v-model is not triggered when I type some text in the q-select. So how can I watch content of q-select with use-input for every character the user type ?

The only solution I see is to keep the two components, a q-input for text entry, and the q-select for selecting results, with style to look like a q-select with use-input attribute :/

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the scope a the `v-slot`:
`<template v-slot:no-option="scope">`
then you have ur `scope.inputValue`   in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I found q-select has an @input-value Event